# Adding Grid of Buttons to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, grid-layout

I'm trying to make a grid of 20px x 20px buttons that I define as "cells", blank by default, no special decorations such as shading, and change color when clicked. (They are meant to show "1" just for testing purposes). I make a Cell class to define these buttons, give each an ActionListener.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Cell implements ActionListener
{
    private JButton button;
    private EditorPanel editorPanel;

    public Cell(EditorPanel editorPanel){
    button = new JButton("1'");
    button.addActionListener(listener -> colorCell());
    button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,20));
    button.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
    button.setOpaque(true);
    button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    this.editorPanel = editorPanel;
    }

public JButton getButton() {
    return button;
}

public void colorCell()
{
    button.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}

}
```

and then use an array of Cell objects (cells) in my EditorPanel class to create a grid of these buttons with dimensions defined by "col" and "row".

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;


import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class EditorPanel{

public JFrame jframe;
public JPanel jpanel;
public static EditorPanel editorPanel;
public Render render;
public static final int col = 45, row = 45,  tile_size=20;
public static final int panelWidth=900, panelHeight=900;
public Dimension dim;
public int coloredPixels;

public Cell[][] cells; 

public void getFrame() {

    editorPanel = new EditorPanel();
    dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    jframe = new JFrame("Pixel Art Creator");
    jframe.setVisible(true);
    jframe.setSize(panelWidth+17, panelHeight+40);
    jframe.setLocation(dim.width/2 - jframe.getWidth()/2, dim.height/2 - jframe.getHeight()/2);
    jframe.add(render = new Render());
    jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

private JPanel addCells()
{
    cells=new Cell[row][col];
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(row, col));
    for(int i = 0; i< row; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<col; j++){
            cells[i][j] = new Cell(this);
            panel.add(cells[i][j].getButton());
        }
    }
    return panel;
}

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    editorPanel = new EditorPanel();
    editorPanel.getFrame();
    editorPanel.addCells();
}

}
```

I then try to add each created Cell object that I attempted to put into the cells array in the addCells() method and add it to my JPanel. When I run this code I don't get any buttons, meaning that these buttons aren't being added to JPanel. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, two "significant" issues:

1. `editorPanel.addCells();` never adds the `JPanel` that it creates to anything, so it will never be displayed
2. Calling `JFrame#setVisible` BEFORE you've finished establishing the UI can cause the UI elements not to show up on the UI.  You can fix this by calling `revalidate` and `repaint` on the container which is changed, but if possible, simply get the UI established first, then make it visible

I would, however, suggest a slight change in approach.  Rather then making `Cell` a class which contains a `JButton`, and then exposing that button to other aspects of your UI, I would make `Cell` a component and simply add it to the what ever container you want, for example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++) {
                gbc.gridy = y;
                for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
                    gbc.gridx = x;
                    add(new Cell(), gbc);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public class Cell extends JPanel {

        public Cell() {
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    colorCell();
                }
            });
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(20, 20);
        }

        protected void colorCell() {
            if (getBackground() != Color.DARK_GRAY) {
                setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            } else {
                setBackground(null);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Now, I've just used a plain old `JPanel` in the this case, but you could just as easily extend from a `JButton` or `JToggledButton` ... but I might be tempted to use a factory pattern instead, but that's me.

The purpose of using a `GridBagLayout` is to allow the frame and outer containers to be resized without changing the size of the `Cell`s themselves, unlike `GridLayout`, which will try and make the cells fill the available space

Comment: Heyo! Thanks for your quick reply. This was absolutely a great idea. I never knew about `setBackground()` and `GridBagLayout` and they were godsends to me for what I was trying to achieve. Using Cell as a component was way __WAY__ easier than using a separate Cell class. Thanks a dozen. Do you happen to know any good online resources that could help me research GUIs?